# Отправить несколько классов в одном post-запросе

Tags: javascript, post, angular2, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2

Приветствую! Требуется отправить из клиента(Angular 5) на сервер(ASP.Net Core WebAPI) объект заказа и компании которой он направлен. Не могу понять как отправить правильно это в одном запросе, т.к. модель на сервере не проходит валидацию(ModelState возвращает Invalid) .

**Код отправки компонента:**

```
    onSubmit() {
    console.log('post ');
    this.order.caption = this.orderForm.value.caption;
    this.order.text = this.orderForm.value.description;
    this.order.cost = this.orderForm.value.cost;
    this.order.upTo = this.orderForm.value.date;

    this.change.emit(this.order);
    console.log(this.order);
    this.ordersService.create(this.order, this.selectedCompany).subscribe(data => {
        console.log('response ' + data);
    },
    error => {
        console.log(error._body);
    });
    this.order = new Order();
}
```

**Код отправки сервиса**

```
create(order: Order, company: Company) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, {order, company});
}
```

**Код обработки контроллера**

```
public IActionResult PostOrders([FromBody]Orders order,[FromBody]Companies company)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Post order:");
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Post order:"+ company.IdCompany);
            Orders neworder = new Orders();

            neworder.Caption = order.Caption;
            neworder.Text = order.Text;
            neworder.Cost = order.Cost;
            neworder.Url = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            neworder.UpTo = order.UpTo;
            neworder.UsersId = 1;

            using(servicedbContext db = new servicedbContext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Post order: " + neworder.Caption.ToString());
                db.Orders.Add(neworder);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine("Post response order: " + neworder.IdOrders.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Post response order: " + neworder.Caption.ToString());
                return Ok(neworder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ModelState.ValidationState);
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Заранее благодарю!